# creating object beforehand in c++

Tags: c++

Here is my concrete example of what I'm trying to do. I need to have a type of object created by the end of this function so I can store it in something else(not created yet), that is either a string, Id, or expression parameter. The problem I am facing is that I don't know what type of object to create if I haven't done logic yet, and If I create the object inside the if statement while I am doing logic, it will exist no more there. I want to store the objects into a vector of type parameter in another class not listed here. at the end of the code

```
bool parameter(Predicate& pred)//look for the following: STRING | ID | expression
{
    //store a parameter in this predicate
    Parameter // <- I don't know which type of object to create yet!!!!
    //create parameter
    get_grammar_type(token, sfile);
    token_type = token.Get_type();
    if(token_type == STRING)
    {
        //would create object of type string here
        //can't create object here. It won't exist after.
    }
    else if(token_type == ID)
    {
     //would create object of ID string here
           //can't create object here. It won't exist after.
    }
    if(expression(pred))
    {
         //would create object of Expression here.can't create object here. It won't exist after.
    }
//store object in object pred here. Pred has a private member of a vector of type parameters within it.
    return true;
}

#ifndef PARAMETER_H
#define PARAMETER_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Predicate.h"

using namespace std;

class Parameter
{

    public:

    private:
}

class String : public Parameter
{
    public:
        insert_string(string in_string);


    private:
        string my_string;

}

class ID : public Parameter
{
    public:
        insert_id(string in_ID);

    private:
        string my_ID;

};


class Expression : public Parameter
{
    private:
        Parameter left_parameter;
        Parameter right_parameter;
        string op;

    public:

};

#endif
```

//also I want to know how I will be able to create left and right parameters in the expression class if i don't know what type they are yet

Comment: I'm not sure if `C++` has `interface`s but that's how I'd do it in `C#`. Create a struct holding the `interface` object and an `enum` so you can cast to the correct type later.

Comment: @JamesHughes C++ has it all and then some :)

Comment: Are you using polymorphism or not?

Comment: since OP has subtypes you should make a pointer to the base class, and dynamically create the child classes, although it would be better to encapsulate the variation inside Parameter so you don't have to do that. Although if you use new, make sure you don't get memory leaks. Every pointer must end up deleted at some point.

Comment: @RawN I've not used much C++ beyond simple command line stuff. I much prefer C#, good to know my suggestion might be helpful though

Comment: The thing is I don't know if I want to create a left and right parameter, a string, and another string every time I want a parameter. I also am going to need to recurse through this, so I want something that is sustainable and fairly simple.

Comment: @JamesHughes I encourage you to try it. I lost all interest in other languages after discovering the above.

Comment: @OP: the best solution is to hide the base class inside another base class. e.g. Parameter is your outer class, and the types all derive from ParameterType. Then Parameter contains a pointer to ParameterType, and you write functions inside Parameter to create all the various types. The you just create a normal e.g. "Parameter param" object in your function, and it calls different methods depending on what your storing in it, e.g. "param.MakeAString(string1)" would create the "String" subobject with the value passed in. Parameter would also handle deleting the dynamic objects in its destructor

Comment: @RawN I've just bought a C++ course on Udemy because they have a massive sale on. One thing that bugs me is the overcomplicated way that it deals with file relationships

Comment: Use the [`std::variant` template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pointers in this case. Create a `Parameter*` variable further up, and dynamically allocate the data structure inside one of your if-statements and assign to that pointer. For example:

```
Parameter *parameter = NULL;
if(token_type == STRING)
{
    parameter = (Parameter*) new String();
}
```

Do something fancier with [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) if you don't want to worry about deallocation.